# nodejs Sequelize orm model.validation not a function

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, sequelize.js

Here is my `User` model definition

```
options: {
        tableName: 'cushbu_users',
        hooks:{},
        timestamps:false,

        /*--field names and validation rules --*/
        email:{
          type:Sequelize.STRING,
          validate:{
              notEmpty:true
          }
        },
        first_name:{
            type:Sequelize.STRING,
            validate:{
                notEmpty:true
            }
        }
    }
```

How can i get the model validation error messages in my controller

I am tried with these

```
 User.validate().success(function () {
             console.log('ok');
         }).error(function (error) {
             console.log(error);
         })
```

But i got following error `user.validate not function`

Comment: Same to me. Have you fixed this issue @Jabaa

Answer (score 1):

you should call this method from instant object not the sequelize model like this:

```
User.create({
        name: "test"
        email: "test"
        password: "test"
    }).then(function(user){
      // validate
       errors = user.validate();

    });
```

Comment: Let me check it

Answer (score 0):

You can add classMethods in Model class and put logic inside this and return errors.

```
classMethods: {
      validator: function() {
        var errors = [];
        if (!this.email){
           errors.push('Email id should not be null');
        }
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
       return errors;
      },
}
```

Call method from your route like `User.validator()`, if it returns empty array then your `User` object is valid else display the error messages.

Comment: But I want the model validations

Comment: Refer -
 http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#validators-and-allownull-